# How to sync git branch on a remote website without git access?

Tags: git, ssh

I have a *live* branch that needs to be *pulled* (git pull) on the live server, but the live server cant acess bitbucket.

While I have ssh access on the remote server using login/pass (cant use ssh-key), what is the best way to syncronize the specified branch on the remote server (updating and deleting changed files)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using rsync.

With rsync I can check witch files were modified and are different on the remote server.

I also created a file named *build.exclude.sync* witch contains every dir I want to skip, and at terminal I can use:

```
rsync -avz --exclude-from=build.exclude.sync /home/path/to/local/dir/ -e ssh myuser@myremotehost.com:/path/to/remote/dir/
```

I used rsync with [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org) to automate the build proccess. At my build.xml file:

```
<exec executable="rsync" dir="." failonerror="true">
         <arg line="-avz --exclude-from=build.exclude.sync ${prod.local.deploydir} -e ssh  ${prod.sshusername}@${prod.sshhost}:${prod.homedir}"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `scp` to copy your files to the server from a machine that does have access to bitbucket instead of using git. Have a cron job pull from bit bucket. Use a post receive hook to kick off the scp command.